# What's causing logcheck to take up 100% of CPU load?

Tags: debian, grep, cpu-usage, logcheck

So multiple (1 per core) `grep` processes by user `logcheck` are taking up 100% of my CPU for a while now. How can I find out what's causing this and how can I fix it without killing the process as I wish for logcheck to run through and create its reports? Or is this normal behavior? (Do others have the same issue? When and how do I know if it has problems?)

I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE but I'm still new to GNU/Linux in general.

Comment: So it took about 2 hours and then went down again. Not sure what caused this.

Comment: I did not see logcheck taking that many resources. Do you use any modifications to the logcheck rules? You could call logcheck manually with an strace call before to see where it consumes that much cpu load.